# What is the difference between present and past participle when they describe a noun?

Tags: participles

What is the difference between present and past participle when they describe a noun?

1. There is a text **asked** me to meet
2. There is a text **asking** me to meet

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a text asked me to meet.

   The past participle of a transitive verb employed as an adjective is understood in a **passive** sense. The noun it modifies is understood to be the subject of a passive expression, which means that it is the 'Patient' of the verb, the entity which is acted upon:

   > The question asked has no answer = *The question was asked by somebody*

   But the *asked* in your example has a direct object, *me*, which has to be its Patient. Consequently, *asked* cannot be parsed as a past participle modifying the text: it has to be the past-tense finite verb in a colloquially reduced relative clause:

   > There is a text [which] asked me to meet.
2. There is a text asking me to meet.

   The present participle of of a transitive verb employed as an adjective is understood in an **active** sense. The noun it modifies is understood to be the subject of an active expression, and therefore the 'Agent' of the verb, the entity which performs the action. In your example we understand that

   > There was a text and it asked me to meet ...